# Should Shebang lines be used in all the programs that would run through Terminal?

Tags: python, macos

My book states that:

> The first line of all your Python programs should be a shebang line, which tells your computer that you want Python to execute this program. The shebang line for OSX is `#! /usr/bin/env python3.`

But my program works perfectly fine without the shebang line in the Terminal. Then should I use it in the future? Also is there a fullstop(.) at the end of the shebang line in OSX or not?

Comment: It's not necessary, you can run your *.py file with python command, you still don't need the shebang, the only case I can think of using shebang, is making your *.py file executable and run it directly just as a shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should not be a full stop at the end of the line.

Whether to add the shebang or not depends on how you want to run it. If you always invoke the interpreter explicitly then it is optional, i.e.

```
$ python3 script.py
```

does not require the shebang, nor does it require executable permission on the file. You can add the shebang, and the code will still run, in which case it might serve as documentation.

However, if you want to execute it like this:

```
$ ./script.py
```

or

```
$ /path/to/script/script.py
```

then you will need to add the shebang *and* set executable permission on the file (see [`chmod`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod)).

Comment: @Rafed,  /path/to/script/script.py as mhawke mentioned, is runing it directly.

Comment: First of all thank you so much for your answer! So what you are saying is that I do not need to use the shebang line if I am opening the file using the IDLE shell or through the terminal. But if I want to open a python file using `$ /path/to/script/script.py` then I will need to have a shebang line as it will give the permission to run the file. Please correct me wherever I am wrong :)

Comment: @Rafedyadav No, to execute the program by path, you need to have a shebang line *and also* set the execute permission on the file. Adding a shebang does nothing to grant that permission.

Comment: @GordonDavisson , And chmod is used to do that?

Comment: @Rafedyadav: Yes, `chmod +x /path/to/script/script.py` will do that. BTW, one way to think about whether you need a shebang: when you run the program, are you thinking "I want to run this program", or "I want to run this *Python* program"? When developing it, you're thinking of it specifically as a Python program, but later when someone is just trying to use it, they no longer care (or maybe even know) what it's written in. Having a shebang and execute permission permits someone to run it without having to worry about what language it's written in.

Comment: @GordonDavisson , this is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot :-)